# Macro doesn't assign intended value to a variable after counting its bits

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I need to write a macro `maxBitsOff` that will count all zeroes in two variables then determine which variable has more zeroes and assign it to the result variable. If two variables to be compared have the same amount of zeroes then the first variable will be assigned to the result.
For example given `maxBitsOff(a, b, result, z)` if `a = 1` and `b = 30` `a` will surely win because there're more zeroes in `1` than in `30`. So we'd assign `a` to the `result` and the number of zeroes to `z`.
After hours of debigging I can't get the macro to work. This is the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "math.h"

#define ARR_LEN 8
#define maxBitsOff(a, b, result, z) { \
    int acount = 0, bcount = 0, i; \
    printf("sizeof(a) = %d\n", sizeof(a)); \
    for(i = 0; i < 8 * sizeof(a); i++) { \
        if(!(a & (1 << i))) { \
            acount++; \
        } \
        if(!(b & (1 << i))) { \
            bcount++; \
        } \
    } \
    if(acount >= bcount) { \
        result = a; \
        z = acount; \
    } else { \
        result = b; \
        z = bcount; \
    } \
    printf("result = %d\n", result); \
    printf("z = %d\n", z); \
}

int main() {
    int arr[ARR_LEN] = {120, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 1};
    int z, i, max = 0;
    int result;

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN - 1; i++) {
        maxBitsOff(arr[i], arr[i + 1], result, z);
        if(max < result)
            max = result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After I run this code I get these results which are clearly bad:

`result = 32767`

`z = 23`

Comment: Just reading title macro can never assign but replace.

Comment: Won't `sizoef(var) * CHAR_BIT` be a much easier way to count the number of bits?

Comment: @StoryTeller He wants the number of 0 bits.  So uint8_t of 0xFF should return 0.

Comment: @Yos You might find it easier if you separate your problems.  Counting the number of 0s should be it's own function/macro.  Then you can just compare the results from two calls to that macro with two vars.

Comment: @RyanB you're probably right but I have to do this in one macro. More importantly I guess I'm missing something basic about working with bits and/or macros which hopefully someone can point out to me.

Comment: "I guess I'm missing something basic about working with bits and/or macros" - in order to eliminate the "bits" problem, convert this macro into a function (which will be a lot easier for you to debug), and make sure that it works correctly.

Comment: @barakmanos did that but still no hints at the the real issue.

Comment: BTW, you may as well use `if (acount >= bcount)` instead of the two separate cases `if (acount == bcount)` and `if (acount > bcount)`.

Comment: @barakmanos nice! I changed the code to make it more readable.

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive is a good resource.  I highly doubt you need to do it in 1 macro.  Macros can reference other macros.  Also, there's two main reasons to use a macro: performance (0 cost abstraction), and generics.

Comment: How does `acount => bcount` even compile? Also, why on earth would you use a macro instead of a function?

Comment: @RyanB thanks for the link. I think the problem in this code is not bit counting but that storing the result value in the result variable doesn't work.

Comment: The last iteration of the `i` loop causes undefined behaviour (left-shift signed value too far), and you use the wrong format specifier for `sizeof`.

Comment: @M.M how should I use `sizeof` in this case then?

Comment: cast result to `int` to match the `%d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro substitution is *text replacement*.

You are using variable `i` in your macro, and passing in `arr[i]`  as a parameter. Try using underscores in your hidden variable names. Also, store the A and B args in temp storage within the block.

Comment: Thank you so much! this WAS the issue, I just corrected it and it now works.

Comment: *Try using underscores in your hidden variable names* - I would prefer a suggestion like: 1) do not use function-like macros at all, or 2) if your *really* need to inline functions in ridiculously tight loops, use `inline` instead.

Comment: Now that you have it working, you should replace the counting with a table lookup of 256 possible byte values.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ARR_LEN` is `8`, and your `for` loop iterates from `0` to `31`, you are reading way past the end of the input array.

Why? Because you're using macros.

Consider what happens when the macro is expanded:

```
for (i = 0; i < ARR_LEN - 1; i++)
{
    // expanded maxBitsOff(arr[i], arr[i + 1], result, z):

    ...

    for (i = 0; i < 8 * sizeof(arr[i]); i++)
    {
        if (!(arr[i] & (1 << i)))   // <-- i goes to 31 here
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly to address another answer here, but here's a faster way to get the bit count:

```
#define BC_OffBitCount(in, out)                                \
  {                                                            \
    out = ~in;                                                 \
    switch (sizeof(in)) {                                      \
      case 4:                                                  \
        out = (out & 0x55555555) + ((out >> 1) & 0x55555555);  \
        out = (out & 0x33333333) + ((out >> 2) & 0x33333333);  \
        out = (out & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((out >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);  \
        out = (out & 0x00FF00FF) + ((out >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);  \
        out = (out & 0x0000FFFF) + ((out >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF); \
        break;                                                 \
      case 2:                                                  \
        out = (out & 0x5555) + ((out >> 1) & 0x5555);          \
        out = (out & 0x3333) + ((out >> 2) & 0x3333);          \
        out = (out & 0x0F0F) + ((out >> 4) & 0x0F0F);          \
        out = (out & 0x00FF) + ((out >> 8) & 0x00FF);          \
        break;                                                 \
      case 1:                                                  \
        out = (out & 0x55) + ((out >> 1) & 0x55);              \
        out = (out & 0x33) + ((out >> 2) & 0x33);              \
        out = (out & 0x0F) + ((out >> 4) & 0x0F);              \
        break;                                                 \
    }                                                          \
  }

#define BC_OffCompareGreater(a, b, out)  // Left as an exercise to the reader
```

And the tests:

```
void test_uint8_t_of_0x00_should_return_8(void) {
  uint8_t value = 0;
  uint8_t result;
  BC_OffBitCount(value, result);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(8, result);
}

void test_uint8_t_of_0x55_should_return_4(void) {
  uint8_t value = 0x55;
  uint8_t result;
  BC_OffBitCount(value, result);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(4, result);
}

void test_uint16_t_of_0xAA_should_return_12(void) {
  uint16_t value = 0xAA;
  uint16_t result;
  BC_OffBitCount(value, result);
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(12, result);
}

void test_uint32_t_of_0xDEADBEEF_should_return_8(void){
    uint32_t value = 0xDEADBEEF;
    uint32_t result;
    BC_OffBitCount(value, result);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(8, result);
}
```

I'm sure there's a clever way to remove the repetition, but that can also be left as an exercise to the reader.

Edit: I copied and modified the code from [hacker's delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321842685).

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm assuming you're making it a macro to avoid the overhead of a function call, here is a very fast macro for counting the bits in a single value.

I think this can be the basis of the comparison you want:

```
#define bitsOffMacro(x, cnt) do {     \
    int _x = x;                        \
    cnt = 32;                           \
    while(_x & -_x){--cnt;_x&=~(_x&-_x);}\
    } while(0)
```

**Outline of the flow:**

- Start the Counter at 32 zeros (assuming 4-byte int)
- While a bit is still found in the value
- Decrement the counter, because we found a bit.
- Turn off that bit
- Repeat until all bits are off.

---

Then use that macro to create:

```
#define getHigherCount(x,y,cnt) do {           \
    int _Xcnt;             int _Ycnt;           \
    bitsOffMacro(x,_Xcnt); bitsOffMacro(y,_Ycnt);\
    cnt = (_Xcnt > _Ycnt)?_Xcnt:_Ycnt;            \
} while(0)
```

---

**Sample Usage**

```
int cnt;
getHigherCount(23, 4, cnt);
printf("Answer is %d\n", cnt); // expected value 31.

// 23 has 4 bits set, and 28 off.
// 4  has 1 bit set, and 31 off.
```

---

**P.S.**

I wrap my macros in `do-while(0)` for two reasons:

1. So that they *must* be called with a semi-colon when used; otherwise you have a missing semicolon after the `while(0)`.
2. It creates a "scope" in which I can make new variables like `_x`, `_Xcnt` and `_Ycnt`

Comment: Do you use `do ... while` in the macro so it doesn't cause issues with semicolon in main?

Comment: This completely omits one of the results the OP was after.

Comment: That is trivial to add.  ***Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.***  Once I've outlined the solution, I consider the details a problem for the poster.  (Your own profile even says, *"I don't believe in answering questions completely."*)

Comment: If I completely and utterly modify the OP's own code, I find it remiss to not at least address all the points in the post.

Comment: Don't say it's fast when it isn't.  You can do this in O(logn) time and O(n) space.

Comment: Show me something faster, and I'll consider it.  This solution is constant-time/constant-space.  It loops a MAXIMUM of 64 times (although in most cases far less), and never uses more than 12 bytes of stack. (which will likely be optimized into registers anyway).

Comment: @abelenky Nope, it's O(n) time for the size of the var.  Just because you wrote it for one size doesn't change the O.  Google bit hacks.  You'll find it quickly enough.

Comment: Now you're trying to answer a question totally different from the one posted. (without actually posting any answer).

Comment: Don't say I never gave you anything, see my answer.  I'm not really sure it's appropriate to have it as an answer to this question, though.  If you want to post a question, I can move the answer there.